# Azure Pipeline generated by Nuke runs job in wrong order

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Maybe I am missing something.
The local Nuke build runs fine, and the generated Azure pipeline puts the job in the correct order. But when Azure runs the pipeline the jobs are being executed in the wrong order. Am I missing something?

The generated Azure pipeline:

```yaml
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# <auto-generated>
#
#     This code was generated.
#
#     - To turn off auto-generation set:
#
#         [AzurePipelines (AutoGenerate = false)]
#
#     - To trigger manual generation invoke:
#
#         nuke --generate-configuration AzurePipelines --host AzurePipelines
#
# </auto-generated>
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

stages:
  - stage: ubuntu_latest
    displayName: 'ubuntu-latest'
    dependsOn: [  ]
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    jobs:
      - job: Clean
        displayName: 'Clean'
        dependsOn: [  ]
        steps:
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuke-temp)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp
              path: .nuke/temp
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuget-packages)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages
              path: $(HOME)/.nuget/packages
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: './build.cmd Clean --skip'
      - job: Restore
        displayName: 'Restore'
        dependsOn: [  ]
        steps:
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuke-temp)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp
              path: .nuke/temp
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuget-packages)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages
              path: $(HOME)/.nuget/packages
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: './build.cmd Restore --skip'
      - job: Compile
        displayName: 'Compile'
        dependsOn: [ Restore, Clean ]
        steps:
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuke-temp)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp
              path: .nuke/temp
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuget-packages)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages
              path: $(HOME)/.nuget/packages
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: './build.cmd Compile --skip'
      - job: StartWebApp
        displayName: 'StartWebApp'
        dependsOn: [ Compile ]
        steps:
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuke-temp)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp
              path: .nuke/temp
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuget-packages)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages
              path: $(HOME)/.nuget/packages
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: './build.cmd StartWebApp --skip'
      - job: FunctionalTests
        displayName: 'FunctionalTests'
        dependsOn: [ Compile, StartWebApp ]
        steps:
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuke-temp)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp
              path: .nuke/temp
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuget-packages)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages
              path: $(HOME)/.nuget/packages
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: './build.cmd FunctionalTests --skip'
      - job: UnitTests
        displayName: 'UnitTests'
        dependsOn: [ Compile ]
        steps:
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuke-temp)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp
              path: .nuke/temp
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuget-packages)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages
              path: $(HOME)/.nuget/packages
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: './build.cmd UnitTests --skip'
      - job: RunTests
        displayName: 'RunTests'
        dependsOn: [ UnitTests, FunctionalTests ]
        steps:
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuke-temp)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp
              path: .nuke/temp
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuget-packages)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages
              path: $(HOME)/.nuget/packages
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: './build.cmd RunTests --skip'
      - job: StopWebApp
        displayName: 'StopWebApp'
        dependsOn: [  ]
        steps:
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuke-temp)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuke-temp
              path: .nuke/temp
          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache (nuget-packages)
            inputs:
              key: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages | **/global.json, **/*.csproj
              restoreKeys: $(Agent.OS) | nuget-packages
              path: $(HOME)/.nuget/packages
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: './build.cmd StopWebApp --skip'
```

The order the jobs are executed makes no sense:

[image]

It looks like the generated pipeline only takes the dependencies into account, and ignores the Trigger and Before statements in the Build.cs file.

```
    Target Clean => _ => _
        .Before(Restore)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            RootDirectory.GlobDirectories("*/bin", "*/obj").ForEach(DeleteDirectory);  
        });

    Target Restore => _ => _
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            DotNetTasks
                .DotNetRestore(solution => solution
                    .SetProjectFile(Solution));
        });

    Target Compile => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Restore, Clean)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            DotNetTasks
                .DotNetBuild(solution => solution
                    .SetProjectFile(Solution)
                    .SetConfiguration(Configuration)
                    .EnableNoRestore());
        });

    Target UnitTests => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Compile)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            DotNetTasks
                .DotNetTest(t => t.SetProjectFile(UnitTestProject)
                    .EnableNoRestore()
                    .EnableNoBuild());
        });

    IProcess WebAppProcess;

    Target StartWebApp => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Compile)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            WebAppProcess = ProcessTasks.StartProcess("dotnet", "run", "GreeterApp");
        });

    Target StopWebApp => _ => _
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            WebAppProcess.Kill();
        });

    Target FunctionalTests => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Compile, StartWebApp)
        .Triggers(StopWebApp)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            DotNetTasks
                .DotNetTest(t => t.SetProjectFile(FunctionalTestProject)
                    .EnableNoRestore()
                    .EnableNoBuild());
        });

    Target RunTests => _ => _.DependsOn(UnitTests, FunctionalTests);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my assumption appears to be true.
When I add a dependency on the StopWebApp target (depends on the FunctionalTests), then the Azure Pipeline runs the jobs in the proper order.